# trying to install fedora on virtual box using the RPM

Tags: fedora, rpm

This is a pretty dumb question.  I am trying to install Fedora on a virtual machine (the open source VirtualBox seems like the best option).  I downloaded it from somewhere, and I have the rpm instead of the iso.  If it were just the ISO I could simply mount it using virtual clone drive and then I would be able to install it on virtualBox, because it would think that it is a cd.  But how do I do that with an RPM?  I get the impression that an RPM is simply a packaging format like a .rar or .zip but how do I install this thing on virtualBox?  Find some kind of unrapper for an rpm and then install?  Or is there a simpler way.

Comment: How big is your RPM? I havn't heard of Fedora actually being distributed as an RPM before.

Comment: It is about 58,303 kb +-.0001 kb :-) 
I believe I got this right from the Fedora website.  Perchance I downloaded the wrong file?

Comment: Seems a bit small for the whole of fedora. There are ways of bootstrapping an installation without and ISO image. I think it can be done with yum, but its fiddly. I believe the XEN hypervisor had a tool called rinse that can do that too. I recommend you go back and download the ISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you're not going to be able to install Fedora onto a VirtualBox VM from the RPM file.  There's nothing out there that will produce an ISO from the RPM, but that's the only type of file your VM will be able to mount as a install medium.  You'll have to download the ISO.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.